# Get Audit Log for Permission changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing

How to get Audit log for permission change in SharePoint Online from Audit Center in the Admin page (https://compliance.microsoft.com/)?  For example, we have a SharePoint site & the permissions for the users & SharePoint groups has been changed from contribute to read. we want to know who changed it. How to find this in the SharePoint Online log?

[According to Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide#site-permissions-activities), it is deprecated. Any workaround this? or how can I find out who changed it in the logs?

check modified site permission:

> Site administrator or owner (or system account) changes the permission level that is assigned to a group on a site. This activity is also logged if all permissions are removed from a group.
> NOTE: This operation has been deprecated in SharePoint Online. To find related events, you can search for other permission-related activities such as Added site collection admin, Added user or group to SharePoint group, Allowed user to create groups, Created group, and Deleted group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the **[Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide#site-permissions-activities)** says, **the "Modified site permissions" operation has been deprecated in SharePoint Online**.

You can narrow the scope by checking which users and groups in the site collection have **Full Control** permission.

Comment: Although that the above is correct, we managed to get the report from the SharePoint Online using this link: `https://YourSPSite/_layouts/15/CustomizeReport.aspx?ReportId=f43c916f-4450-4737-b889-8078c9826841&Category=Auditing`